# Cambiar valores de eje x a fechas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, dataframe

estoy trabajando con un archivo que contiene 6 columnas: año, mes, dia, precipitacion, temperatura maxima y temperatura minima. Escribí una función para que se impriman los valores entre una fecha inicial y una fecha final dada, luego de eso puedo escoger si imprimir un gráfico o no.

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

print("""Utilice las funciones:
temperatura()
precipitaciones()""")

f= pd.DataFrame(data=np.genfromtxt("file.txt", delimiter="\t", dtype=(int,int,int,float,float,float)))

def temperatura (año_i,mes_i,dia_i,año_f,mes_f,dia_f):

    x=(datetime.date(year=año_i,month=mes_i,day=dia_i).toordinal())-int(696517) #696517 equivale al 1-1-1908
    y=(datetime.date(year=año_f,month=mes_f,day=dia_f).toordinal())-int(696516) #696516 equivale al 31-12-1907

    print("Dia Mes Año   Mínima Máxima")
    print(f[x:y][["f2","f1","f0","f5","f4"]].to_string(index = False))

    print("Temperatura mínima media: "+ str(np.around(np.mean(f[x:y]["f5"]),decimals=1))+"°C")
    print("Temperatura máxima media: "+ str(np.around(np.mean(f[x:y]["f4"]),decimals=1))+"°C")

    question=input("Para gráfico escriba si: ")
    if question=="si":
        plt.plot(f[x:y][["f5","f4"]])
        plt.xlabel("Fecha")
        plt.ylabel("Temperatura (°C)")
        plt.show()
    else:
        print()
```

El código anterior, seleccionando datos de junio de 1999, me imprime el siguiente gráfico:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Intento cambiar el valor del eje x por fechas, añadiendo una linea a la parte if del código (la primera luego de la declaración if)

```
if question=="si":
    f.index=pd.to_datetime(f.index,origin=datetime.date(year=año_i,month=mes_i,day=dia_i))
    plt.plot(f[x:y][["f5","f4"]])
    plt.xlabel("Fecha")
    plt.ylabel("Temperatura (°C)")
    plt.show()
```

Pero el gráfico termina así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: ¿Tienes un fragmento de tus datos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asumo por lo que explicas y por la forma de parser que el fichero tien una estructura tal que:

> ```
> 1908  1   1   47  22  7
> 1908  1   2   23  27  53
> 1908  1   3   3   12  51
> 1908  1   4   6   13  34
> ...
> ```

Usando una tabulación como separador de columnas.

Dicho ésto, creo que estás desaprovechando lo que pandas ofrece, yo haría lo siguiente:

- Cargar el archivo (es básicamente un csv) con Pandas y no con NumPy.
- Parsear las tres columnas que conforma la fecha y generar una columna de tipo `datetime` y asignarla como índice.
- Asignarles a las otras columnas sus nombres correspondientes para que sea todo más legible.

Eso te da un DataFrame como el siguiente:

```
            Precipitación  Temperatura máxima  Temperatura mínima
Fecha                                              
1999-01-01             47                  22                   7
1999-01-02             23                  27                  53
1999-01-03              3                  12                  51
1999-01-04              6                  13                  34
1999-01-05             24                  59                  14
```

Hecho ésto graficar es trivial usando `pandas.DataFrame.plot`, tu problema con las fechas deja de existir directamente.

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

pd.plotting.register_matplotlib_converters()

print("""Utilice las funciones:
temperatura()
precipitaciones()""")

df = pd.read_csv(
    "file.txt", delimiter="\t", header=None,
    parse_dates={'Fecha': [1, 2, 0]}, index_col="Fecha"
    )
df.columns = ["Precipitación", "Temperatura máxima", "Temperatura mínima"]

def temperatura(año_i, mes_i, dia_i, año_f, mes_f, dia_f):
    x = datetime.date(year=año_i, month=mes_i, day=dia_i)
    y = datetime.date(year=año_f, month=mes_f, day=dia_f)
    selec = df.loc[x: y, ["Temperatura máxima", "Temperatura mínima"]]

    print(selec.to_string())
    print(f"Temperatura mínima media: {selec['Temperatura mínima'].mean():.1f}°C")
    print(f"Temperatura máxima media: {selec['Temperatura máxima'].mean():.1f}°C")

    question = input("Para gráfico escriba si: ")
    if question == "si":
        selec.plot(y=["Temperatura máxima", "Temperatura mínima"], x_compat=True)
        plt.xlabel("Fecha")
        plt.ylabel("Temperatura (°C)")
        plt.show()
    else:
        print()
```

> ```
> >>> temperatura(1999, 6, 1, 1999, 6, 30)
>
>             Temperatura máxima  Temperatura mínima
> Fecha                                             
> 1999-06-01                  38                  45
> 1999-06-02                  19                  11
> 1999-06-03                  44                  36
> 1999-06-04                  12                  24
> 1999-06-05                  12                  35
> 1999-06-06                  10                  20
> 1999-06-07                  58                  27
> 1999-06-08                  17                  19
> 1999-06-09                  44                  28
> 1999-06-10                  43                  33
> 1999-06-11                  44                  37
> 1999-06-12                  17                  12
> 1999-06-13                  15                  45
> 1999-06-14                  16                  45
> 1999-06-15                  35                   2
> 1999-06-16                  41                  21
> 1999-06-17                  46                  32
> 1999-06-18                  24                  22
> 1999-06-19                  15                   2
> 1999-06-20                  45                  15
> 1999-06-21                   5                   4
> 1999-06-22                  32                  49
> 1999-06-23                  41                  50
> 1999-06-24                  42                  19
> 1999-06-25                  15                   3
> 1999-06-26                   6                  22
> 1999-06-27                   1                  51
> 1999-06-28                  33                   6
> 1999-06-29                  27                  17
> 1999-06-30                  45                  16
> Temperatura mínima media: 24.9°C
> Temperatura máxima media: 28.1°C
> Para gráfico escriba si: si
> ```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El formato con el que se muestra la fecha en el eje se puede modificar a tu antojo si lo deseas, cambiando el orden de año-mes-dia, dia-mes-año, usar `Jan`, `Feb`... o `Ene`, `Feb` para los meses, etc.

---

> ** Los datos provienen de un archivo generado aleatoriamente para reproducir el código, por si a alguien le interesa:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta
import random


start_date = date(1908, 1, 1)
end_date = date(2020, 1, 1)

delta = end_date - start_date

with open("file.txt", "w") as file:
    for i in range(delta.days + 1):
        day = start_date + timedelta(days=i)
        file.write((f"{day.year}\t{day.month}\t{day.day}\t"
                    f"{random.randint(0, 60)}\t"
                    f"{random.randint(-15, 20)}\t"
                    f"{random.randint(-2, 35)}\n")
                   )
```

Comment: Genial, aún me encuentro leyendo la documentación de Pandas a modo de aprendizaje, muchisimas gracias!